# Data binding between a navigation main page and subsequent views / pages

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have got a base XAML page which is the basis for a navigation layout, with buttons on the top opening various views in the middle. This is done using a navigation `Frame` and `UriMapper`.

I've placed a few controls (`DatePicker`s to be exact) on the navigation panel, as they will be needed by the views to filter out data.

However, I don't know how to apply any kind of data binding to the subsequent views, which are, after all, separate XAML files.

I need to be able to read the values from the `DataPicker`s and, ideally, react to the values being changed by the user.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would be inclined to do.

Create a `CriteriaService` class using this pattern:-

```
 public CriteriaService : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      private DateTime myStartDate;
      public DateTime StartDate
      {
           get { return myStartDate; }
           set { myStartDate = value; //Notify property changed }
      }

      // Other criteria properties here

      //INotifyPropertyChanged implemenation
 }
```

Now add an instance of this service to App.Xaml.cs:-

```
 <local:CriteriaService x:Key="CritreaService" />
```

In your main page your do something like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource CriteriaService}">
```

so that you can use simple bindings like `SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"` in your criteria controls.

Now in your various pages you have a choice.  In code you can access the `CriteriaService` as:-

```
CriteriaService criteria = App.Resources["CriteriaServices"] as CriteriaService;
```

Or if you want to bind to values from it in your page xaml you can use something like:-

```
 <local:SomeStrangeControl StartDate="{Binding StartDate Source={StaticResource CriteriService}}" />
```

Comment: I've had some problems with the static resources (not your fault at all, I'm just using code partially generated by RIA services), but other than that, it seems to work! :) Thanks!

Comment: I've got one more question regarding this (I hope you'll read this). I've bound the two `DateTimePicker` controls to the `DateTime` fields in the `CriteriaService`. Since one represents a "start date" and the other an "end date", I need to make sure the end isn't "earlier" than the start. Using setters it was easy, and the value is set correctly, however the actual SL `DateTimePicker` controls still show the old selection. I've even bound `DisplayDate`, but it's still the same. What am I missing?